# Javascript DOM elements access by id without using functions

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript so while doing some learning i find out that elements with some id available just like

html part

```
<canvas id="someid"><canvas>
```

js part

```
someid.someProperty = something; // works as well as getElementById('someid')
```

But in all tutorials i found it's told to use getElementById.
Sow what benefits of one or another ways of doing this? What way should i prefer?
Checked in Firefox, Opera, DWB and geany internal browser(webkit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `document.getElementById("whatever")` in all cases.  Here are some of the relevant issues:

Using the automatic global variable has these issues:

- Not a standard defined behavior
- Not supported in all browsers
- Vulnerable to global namespace clashes
- Some name attributes (but not all) can be used this way
- Can have collisions between id and name
- Code is less readable because the reader has to figure out whether you're using a global variable that you've previously put a value in or whether this is an automatically defined variable.

Using `document.getElementById()`:

- Is supported by the standard
- Is supported in all browsers
- Does not rely on any global variables
- Unambiguous behavior in all uses

Answer (score 1):

Some browsers create implicit global variables for named DOM elements. Referencing an element this way in Firefox produces the following warning:

> "Element referenced by ID/NAME in the global scope. Use W3C standard
>   document.getElementById() instead."

Follow that warning's advice. Using `getElementById`:

- is supported by the standard
- is explicit (and therefore more clear)
- requires you to create an appropriately-scoped variable for each element you want to reference
- is more recognizable to modern developers

There are no good reasons to use the non-standard method.

Answer (score 0):

For JS you plan to write it's always good to manually bound variables to DOM elements, otherwise you could get undesired results if some Object is bound to the `window` object and shared the same ID name as your element

```
var someid = {}; // Some Object

someid.style.color = "red";  // DOM element remains untouched
// we just nested properties and values to the 'someid' Object.
// #someid text has not become red.

var myElement = document.getElementById('someid');
// var myElement = querySelector('#someid');
myElement.style.color = "red";
// Wow, now it is
```